# Combine microdata to optimize website - Is combining OK?

Tags: html5, microdata

I have an SEO question, I can't find out if it's OK, that's reason why I ask.

I defined my *breadcrumb* from main navi with help from [Rich Snippets – Breadcrumbs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/185417?hl=de), by using its "data-vocabulary". Is this OK if I use the `shema.org` website structure?

My structure is like this:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
<header itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader">
<ul>
<li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a itemprop="url" href=""><span itemprop="title">linktext</span></a></li>
</ul>
</header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may use different *vocabularies* (like Schema.org and Data-Vocabulary.org) in the same document.

Microdata ([in contrast to RDFa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25888436/1591669)) has rather limited support for mixed vocabulary use for *the same content*, so if you decide to use Schema.org’s [`BreadcrumbList`](http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList) together with Data-Vocabulary.org’s [`Breadcrumb`](http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb) in the future, you would have to duplicate your content.
With RDFa, you could easily use both vocabularies for the very same content.

Comment: Side note: if the vocabulary structure allows it, it can be possible to mix vocabularies for the same content (see [examples with Schema.org-`BreadcrumbList` and Data-Vocabulary.org-`Breadcrumb`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45525489/1591669))